# Discord js v13 channel filter not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, embed

I'm currently trying to get the total amount of text channels and voice channels to display in my embed, when I try to filter them as I did in discord.js v12 it gives me an output of 0 but if I use no filter and do guild.channels.cache.size, it prints 4 which is the correct amount ( 2 text channels, 1 voice channel , 1 category channel).

If anyone can explain why it's printing 0 and not the correct amount of text/voice channels that would be amazing, I've searched everywhere and can't find a reason why it wouldn't work.

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

// EXPORT SERVERINFO COMMAND DATA TO NODE
module.exports = ({
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('serverinfo')
        .setDescription('Basic Server Info.'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        // REFERENCE THE GUILD
        const guild = interaction.guild;
        // CREATE TEST EMBED
        const serverInfoEmbed = new MessageEmbed();
        serverInfoEmbed.setColor('#36393F');
        serverInfoEmbed.setAuthor('Fyce Bot - /serverinfo', interaction.user.avatarURL(), 'https://github.com/ttommie/fyce-bot/');
        serverInfoEmbed.setTitle('Server Information');
        serverInfoEmbed.setThumbnail(guild.iconURL());
        serverInfoEmbed.addFields(
            { name: 'Name', value: `${guild.name}`, inline: true },
            { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B', inline: true },
            { name: 'Owner', value: `<@${guild.ownerId}>`, inline: true },
            { name: 'Total Members', value: `${guild.memberCount}`, inline: true },
            { name: 'Users Count', value: `${guild.members.cache.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size}`, inline: true },
            { name: 'Bots Count', value: `${guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.user.bot).size}`, inline: true },
            { name: 'Text Channels', value: `${guild.channels.cache.filter(channels => channels.type === 'text').size}`, inline: true }, // PROBLEM HERE 
            { name: 'Voice Channels', value: `${guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type === 'voice').size}`, inline: true }, // PROBLEM HERE 
            { name: 'Roles Count', value: `${guild.roles.cache.size}`, inline: true },
        );
        serverInfoEmbed.setFooter(`${guild.name} - Date Created`);
        serverInfoEmbed.setTimestamp(`${guild.createdAt.toUTCString().substr(0, 16)}`);

        await interaction.reply({ embeds: [serverInfoEmbed] });
    },
});
```

Comment: You do not have to write "[SOLVED]" in your title. Accepting an answer signals everyone that your question has been successfully answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discord.js v13 changed the possible values of [`Channel.type`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ChannelType).

Here is how you change it

```
//text channel filter
- guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type === 'text')
+ guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type === 'GUILD_TEXT')

//vc filter
- guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type === 'voice')
+ guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type === 'GUILD_VOICE')

//category filter
- guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type === 'category')
+ guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type === 'GUILD_CATEGORY')
```

Replace whatever is preceded with a `-` with the text below which is preceded with a `+`

Answer (score 1):

Discord.js v14 updated the way you reference [Channel.type](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v14.html#removal-of-method-based-type-guards)

Here is how you change it

```
// import Channel Types
+ const { ChannelType } = require('discord.js');

//text channel filter
- guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type === 'GUILD_TEXT')
+ guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type === ChannelType.GuildText)

//vc filter
- guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type === 'GUILD_VOICE')
+ guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type === ChannelType.GuildVoice)

//category filter
- guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type === 'GUILD_CATEGORY')
+ guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type === ChannelType.GuildCategory)
```

Replace whatever is preceded with a `-` with the text below which is preceded with a `+`

Answer (score -1):

I tried Tommie's way but it didn't work, so I find this on Dev's Portal and it worked:

[Use the integer values to filter the type.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzbTg.png)

I did like this to filter text channels:

`guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type === 0)`

Hope it helps someone!

(https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#channel-object-channel-types)

Comment: Yes using the ID's for the specific channelTypes works as well although they are directly connected to the enum defined in the discord js lib, as long as you require the ChannelType enumeration from the lib you should be able to call the channel type by the name so it's odd to see it not working properly.

Comment: You must be using discord.js v14. This question was created with discord.js v13/